# code not throwing exception in unit testing

Tags: scala, scalatest, playframework-2.6

The following code should throw an exception in case of unexpected situation

```
     def remove(loginInfo: LoginInfo): Future[Unit] = Future{
        println("In PasswordRepository, removing password")//TODOM - any print statements should not reveal confidential information
        val bucketId = utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(loginInfo.providerKey)
        val userFutureOption = userRepo.findOne(UserKeys(bucketId,loginInfo.providerKey,loginInfo))
        userFutureOption.flatMap(userOption =>{ userOption match {
          case Some(user) => {
            println("setting password info to None") //TODOM - need to check that passwordInfo isn't empty

val updatedUser = User(user.id,
              UserProfile(Some(InternalUserProfile(user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.loginInfo,
                bucketId,
                user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed,
                None)),ExternalUserProfile(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email,
                user.profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName,
                user.profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName,
                user.profile.externalProfileDetails.password))) //don't need to store password explicitly. It is in PasswordInfo field already
            println("updated user "+updatedUser)
            val userFutureOption = userRepo.update(updatedUser)
            userFutureOption.map(userOption => {
              userOption match {//do nothing in Some as the function returns Unit
                case Some(user) => {
                  Unit
                }
                case None => {
                  println("error in deleting password info of the user")
                  //TODOM - funtion is not throwing the Exception. Need to check
                  throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(langs.availables(0))) 
                }
              }
            })
          }
          case None => {
            println("user not found. Can't remove password info. This shouldn't have happened")
            throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(langs.availables(0)))
          }
        }
        })
      }
```

When I unit-test the code, the code doesn't throw the exception. Why?

```
  "PasswordRepository Specs" should {
    "should return error if password cannot be deleted for an existing user" in {

      val user = repoTestEnv.testEnv.user 
      when(repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository.findOne(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Future{Some(repoTestEnv.testEnv.user)})
      when(repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository.update(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Future{None}) //this should trigger the throw exception code
      val passwordRepository = new PasswordRepository(repoTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods,repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository,repoTestEnv.testEnv.messagesApi,repoTestEnv.testEnv.langs)
          val exception = intercept[java.lang.Exception]( await[Unit](passwordRepository.remove(repoTestEnv.testEnv.loginInfo))(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis"))))
      println(s"exception is ${exception}")
      exception.getMessage() mustBe repoTestEnv.testEnv.messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(repoTestEnv.testEnv.langs.availables(0))

    }
  }
```

I get the error

```
=== starting new test case execution ====
In PasswordRepository, removing password
setting password info to None
updated user User(11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111,UserProfile(Some(InternalUserProfile(LoginInfo(credentials,test@test.com),1,true,None)),ExternalUserProfile(test@test.com,fn,ln,Some(somePassword))))
error in deleting password info of the user
=== ending test case execution ====

Expected exception java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but no exception was thrown
```

Update
The behavior is peculiar because the unit tests work for `add` method which is very similar to the `remove` method.

```
 def add(loginInfo: LoginInfo, authInfo: PasswordInfo): Future[PasswordInfo] = {
    println(s"in PasswordRepository add ${loginInfo.providerID}, ${loginInfo.providerKey}, ${authInfo.hasher}, ${authInfo.password},${authInfo.salt}")
    val bucketId = utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(loginInfo.providerKey)
    val userFutureOption = userRepo.findOne(UserKeys(bucketId,loginInfo.providerKey,loginInfo))
    userFutureOption.flatMap(userOption =>{ userOption match {
      case Some(user) => {
        println("adding password info "+ authInfo+ "to user "+user) //TODOM - need to check that passwordInfo isn't empty
        val updatedUser = User(user.id,
          UserProfile(Some(InternalUserProfile(user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.loginInfo,
            bucketId,
            user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.confirmed,
            Some(authInfo))),ExternalUserProfile(user.profile.externalProfileDetails.email,
            user.profile.externalProfileDetails.firstName,
            user.profile.externalProfileDetails.lastName,
            user.profile.externalProfileDetails.password))) //don't need to store password explicitly. It is in PasswordInfo field already
        println("updated user "+updatedUser)
        //TODOM is there a risk if email id gets updated. Then it should be updated in both email and loginInfo
        val userUpdateFutureOption = userRepo.update(updatedUser)
        userUpdateFutureOption.map(userOption => {
          userOption match {
          case Some(user) => {
            //TODOM - should not access PasswordInfo directly
            println("returning PassswordInfo "+user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo)
            //TODOM - check for empty for both internalProfileDetails and passwordInfo in Functional way
            user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.passwordInfo.get
          }
          case None => {
            println("error in updating password info of the user")
            //authInfo //TODOM - I should throw an exception from this Future.
            throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordConfigureError")(langs.availables(0)))
          }
        }
        })
      }
      case None => {
        println("user not found. Can't set password info. This shouldn't have happened")
        throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordConfigureError")(langs.availables(0)))
      }
    }
    })
  }
```

The following test case passes for `add`

```
  "PasswordRepository Specs" should {
    "should return error if password cannot be updated for an existing user when adding a password" in {

      val newPassword = PasswordInfo("newHasher","newPassword",Some("newSalt"))
      val user = repoTestEnv.testEnv.user

      when(repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository.findOne(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Future{Some(repoTestEnv.testEnv.user)})
      when(repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository.update(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Future{None})
      val passwordRepository = new PasswordRepository(repoTestEnv.testEnv.mockHelperMethods,repoTestEnv.mockUserRepository,repoTestEnv.testEnv.messagesApi,repoTestEnv.testEnv.langs)

      println(s"adding password ${newPassword}")
      val exception = intercept[java.lang.Exception]( await[PasswordInfo](passwordRepository.add(repoTestEnv.testEnv.loginInfo,newPassword))(Timeout(Duration(5000,"millis"))))
      println(s"exception is ${exception}")
      exception.getMessage() mustBe repoTestEnv.testEnv.messagesApi("error.passwordConfigureError")(repoTestEnv.testEnv.langs.availables(0))

    }
  }
```

It seems the function is not throwing any Exceptions at all because doing this doesn't work either

```
val userUpdateFutureOption = userRepo.update(updatedUser)
        throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(langs.availables(0)))

        userUpdateFutureOption.map(userOption => {...}
```

but if I throw the exception at the very beginning of the code then the test passes

```
val userFutureOption = userRepo.findOne(UserKeys(bucketId,loginInfo.providerKey,loginInfo))
    throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(langs.availables(0)))...
```

Comment: Is `userFutureOption` a real Future ? Or future is just for the variable name ?

Answer (score 0):

The exception is thrown asynchronously in `userFutureOption` because it's a Future, the computation is not in your main thread. 
The exception is therefore not propagated to the test result.

You need to use the method `onComplete` :

```
userFutureOption onComplete {
  case Success(user) => // OK
  case Failure(t) => // KO
}
```

[Here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) is some documentation about Futures in Scala.

Comment: but `await` should wait for the `Future` to finish, isn't it?

Comment: At this line `val userFutureOption = userRepo.update(updatedUser)`, this a new Future ? Not the one return by your function `remove`

Comment: but for that, I am using `map` on the `Future`. So I suppose my code will wait for the result of `userRepo.update(updatedUser)` to be available, isn't it (`userFutureOption.map(userOption => {...}`)?

Comment: The code is executed is the inital thread, here is an example I've found https://scastie.scala-lang.org/z4bNzF6JTtSLfJJ9QHUFjg

Comment: I'll check. In the meanwhile, I have updated the question. For a very similar method `add`, a very similar test case works. so I don't know why the test doesn't work for `remove`.

Comment: It looks very similar to `add` indeed. Do you reach the 5 seconds timeout with `remove` ?

Comment: No, it just fails

Comment: Could you try to throw an exception just before the `map()` ? To see if the exception is correctly propagated ?

Comment: I did this this `throw new Exception(messagesApi("error.passwordDeleteError")(langs.availables(0)))

        userUpdateFutureOption.map(userOption => {...} ` but the test still failed with the same reason

Comment: but if I throw the exception at the very beginning of the code then the test passes. Please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

I got it working though I don't clearly understand why. There was one big difference between the `add` and `remove` methods.

```
def add(...):Future[PasswordInfo] = {...}

def remove(...):Future[Unit] = Future {...} //notice the Future
```

My doubt was always on the use of `Unit` in `remove`. To experiment, I changed the method's return to Future[Int]

```
def remove1:Future[Int] = Future[...] = 
{

...
userUpdateFutureOption.map(userOption => {
          userOption match {//do nothing in Some as the function returns Unit
            case Some(user) => {
              //println("password removed")
              1
            }
...
}
```

and the code stopped compiling complaining that

```
Error:(171, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
 required: Int
    userFutureOption.flatMap(userOption =>{ userOption match {
```

Hovering over the code showed the error `Expression of type Future[Future[Int]] doesn't conform to type Future[Int]`

It seems `Unit` was hiding the Future within the Future but I don't know why. I'll be happy to accept an answer which could explain what is happening under the hood here.

Comment: For someone looking for further explanation, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116591/is-futurefutureunit-same-as-futureunit-why?noredirect=1#comment100752486_57116591