# Is Future[Future[Unit]] same as Future[Unit]. Why?

Tags: scala

Why in the following code, the compiler doesn't give error even if the return type is `Future[Future[Unit]]` instead of `Future[Unit]`?

```
//compiles even though return is Future[Future[Unit]]. Not expected.
   def test1:Future[Unit] = Future{
    Future{   println("something")}
   }
   //doesn't compile because return is Future[Future[Int]] . Expected
   def test:Future[Int] = Future{
       Future{1}
   }
```

Comment: This is due the compiler rewrites the code as: `Future{ Future{ println("something") }; () }` - As you can see, the **Unit** is being inserted at the end of the method. To prevent this, enable the `-Ywarn-value-discard` compiler flag.

Comment: Thanks But why is compiler doing this?

Comment: So you can write this `def foo(): Unit = { a += 1 }` or things like that, the idea is that if unit is expected, it will insert it for you, so you do not have to write it manually. For java-like code it is useful, but for more pure code that can cause troubles. That is why the compiler flag exists, you should always use it, together with all [these](https://tpolecat.github.io/2017/04/25/scalac-flags.html).